# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isCtrlPressed(Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/view/KeyEventCompatHoneycomb;

Tags: android, android-support-library

I got this type of error while executing App.

My code is work in support library 24.2.0 (Android studio in Linux operating system) and when I run this code in windows operating system I got some error, for that solution I upgrade my support library to 25.0.0 and it resolve but now below mentioned error generated.

```
compileSdkVersion = 25
buildToolsVersion = '25.0.0'
supportLibraryVersion = '25.0.0'
targetSdkVersion = 25

E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isCtrlPressed(Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/view/KeyEventCompatHoneycomb; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.KeyEventCompatHoneycomb' appears in /data/app/com.xxx/base.apk:classes23.dex)
 at android.support.v4.view.KeyEventCompat$HoneycombKeyEventVersionImpl.isCtrlPressed(KeyEventCompat.java:120)
 at android.support.v4.view.KeyEventCompat.isCtrlPressed(KeyEventCompat.java:197)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:532)
 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:57)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:315)
 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3434)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved This Issue. 
Make sure your buildToolVersion, CompileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion match with your support library.

In below configuration I got error,

```
compileSdkVersion = 24
buildToolsVersion = '24.0.2'
targetSdkVersion = 24
supportLibraryVersion = '24.2.0'
```

So, I updated to

```
compileSdkVersion = 25
buildToolsVersion = '25.0.0'
targetSdkVersion = 25
supportLibraryVersion = '25.0.1'
```

and that's resolved my issue. Make sure it must match with Major release version.

Comment: must match with major release version

Comment: Can you please expand on your solution as I have same issue on Linux. Are you suggesting that all versions must be the same? This prevents me entering text into edit text

Comment: Hi @Mat, I updated my answer so you can see now. May it help you.

Comment: Thank you Sanjay but this does not assist me to solve my issue.