# Error "No static method isCtrlPressed" in Android

Tags: android

Yesterday I've upgraded my android studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3.
Then get a error

> Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (24.0.2) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0"

when i trying to build my project.

So, i change project gradle file to

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
targetSdkVersion 25

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
```

seems everything is ok, I have successfully run my APP.
but when i tap back button on the phone.
APP crashed.

Also,I've referenced this post [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isCtrlPressed(Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477262/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-isctrlpressedlandroid-view-keyeve)

```
03-07 15:04:32.375 7133-7133/com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
03-07 15:04:32.375 7133-7133/com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-07 15:04:32.385 7133-7133/com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isCtrlPressed(Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/view/KeyEventCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.KeyEventCompat' appears in /data/app/com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:532)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:57)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:315)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2682)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5273)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5226)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4692)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4834)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4700)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4891)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4692)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4700)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4692)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4867)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5110)
                                                                                 at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2877)
                                                                                 at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2449)
                                                                                 at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2440)
                                                                                 at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2854)
                                                                                 at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
                                                                                 at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
03-07 15:04:32.385 7133-7133/com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime, PID: 7133
                                                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isCtrlPressed(Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/view/KeyEventCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.KeyEventCompat' appears in /data/app/com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:532)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:57)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:315)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2682)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5273)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5226)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4692)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4834)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4700)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4891)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4692)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4700)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4692)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4867)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5110)
                                                                               at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2877)
                                                                               at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2449)
                                                                               at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2440)
                                                                               at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2854)
                                                                               at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

> 03-07 15:57:04.595 12048-12054/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
>   03-07 15:58:07.620 12048-12048/com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime, PID: 12048
>                                                                                java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime.PersonalHomepage.PersonalHomePageActivity due to bad method java.lang.Object com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime.PersonalHomepage.PersonalHomePageActivity.access$super(com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime.PersonalHomepage.PersonalHomePageActivity, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) (declaration of 'com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime.PersonalHomepage.PersonalHomePageActivity' appears in /data/app/com.youhong.cuptime.cuptime-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Use the latest, please. `25.2.0`

Comment: Sounds weird. Nevertheless your Buildtools and AppCompat-Lib are still outdated. Try use the current one `buildToolsVersion 25.0.2` and the current appcompat: `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0"`

Comment: @Christopher Tried,  but get a error after app run.

Comment: @Christopher I'll put it on above, take a look.

Comment: No real idea. Can you perform a full rebuild? Maybe an InstantRun issue?

Comment: I'm guessing that you were inputting data into an EditText View at the time you encountered this error?

Comment: @Mat No, I just tapped the back key on the phone, it's relative with "ActivityCompat".Because  I've tried to change my Activity to extends from  "Activity" then everything is gone.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am gettiing the same problem for which I can not find a work-around except to extend Activity but that will mean a lot of change for my project so I want to avoid it.

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as accepted so that we can close this issue?

Comment: I do not know why the solution failed for me under some conditions, anyway, once agaiin I tried your solution and the problem is fixed. After the solution attempts I had tried, this is such a simple fix! Thank you 郭玉龙.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's problem was caused when tapping the hardware back button when subclassing AppCompatActivity. The workaround was to subclass the Activity class.